# android rotate layout with handler

Tags: android, android-layout, rotation, android-animation

i try to rotate layout with handler.i wrote some code

```
void handlechange() {

    Handler hand = new Handler();
    hand.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            change();

        }

        private void change() {

            myImage.setRotation(5);


            handlechange();
        }
    }, 500);

}
```

i can rotate layout but i want to rotate layout every time. 500 milisecond.
setRotate working only one time.
how i can solve my problem? if anyone knows solution please help me

Comment: With a rotation animation I guess.

Comment: @Pedro Oliveira i also tryed animation but i want to rotate with handler

Comment: Why is that? An Animation seems to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: simply use ObjectAnimator or ViewPropertyAnimator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will rotate any view you want. Will increment 5 to it's rotation every 500ms. Change the values to what you want.

```
public void rotateImage(final View myView) {
        final Handler myHandler = new Handler();
        myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myView.setRotation(myView.getRotation() + 5);
                rotateImage(myView);
            }
        }, 500);
    }
```

Notice the `myView.getRotation() + 5`. Otherwise you're setting the rotation to 5 every time.